# Mean app in Docker Containar

Tags: node.js, docker, mean-stack

I'm trying to put Mean app in docker containar but I get this error :

```
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno 34
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/-/mongoose-4.4.6.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/-/mongodb-2.0.55.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.12.4.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/-/mongoose-4.4.6.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.12.4.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/-/mongodb-2.0.55.tgz
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /src/npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

this is my **package.json** :

```
   {
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.4",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "^2.3.4",
    "express": "~4.12.4",
    "jade": "~1.9.2",
    "mongodb": "~2.0.33",
    "mongoose": "^4.2.5",
    "monk": "https://github.com/vccabral/monk.git",

  }
}
```

and the containar is not created,any suggestion ? Thank you!

Comment: What version of docker are you running, and what platform is it running on? (e.g. running on OS X / Boot2Docker, or Ubuntu 15.10). Wondering if this is similar to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20658

Comment: Docker version 1.8.2-el7.centos, build a01dc02/1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example of node js site ( https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/)
JUST put in the Dockerfile " FROM node:argon "